# I want to load my model, but this error appears RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BaseResNet: Missing key(s) in state_dict:

Tags: python, model, streamlit

I want to load my model, but this error appears RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BaseResNet: Missing key(s) in state_dict:

#### This is my model

I'm using resnet18 architecture for my model

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()

        # Main path
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)

        # Shortcut connection
        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or in_channels != out_channels:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x

        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)

        out += self.shortcut(residual)
        out = self.relu(out)

        return out

class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_class=6):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)

        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(64, 64, blocks=2, stride=1)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(64, 128, blocks=2, stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(128, 256, blocks=2, stride=2)

        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
        self.fc = nn.Linear(256, n_class)

    def _make_layer(self, in_channels, out_channels, blocks, stride):
        layers = []
        layers.append(ResidualBlock(in_channels, out_channels, stride))
        for _ in range(1, blocks):
            layers.append(ResidualBlock(out_channels, out_channels, stride=1))
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)

        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc(x)

        return x

class BaseResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_class=6):
        super(BaseResNet, self).__init__()
        self.resnet = ResNet(n_class=n_class)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return x

# Use BaseResNet as the model
model = BaseResNet(n_class=6)
```

##### This is how i save my model

I suspect there might be an error in saving the model data in this part

```
    if VAL_ACC[-1] > best_val_acc:
        best_val_acc = VAL_ACC[-1]
        best_epoch = e
        # Pastikan direktori ada sebelum menyimpan checkpoint
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path), exist_ok=True)
        torch.save({
            'epoch': e + 1,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'train_loss': TRAIN_LOSS[-1],
            'train_acc': TRAIN_ACC[-1],
            'val_loss': VAL_LOSS[-1],
            'val_acc': VAL_ACC[-1],
        }, checkpoint_path)
```

##### This is how load my model in my streamlit code

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st

# Assuming you have already loaded your model and class labels
import torch.nn as nn

class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
  ....MY MODEL CODE....

    def forward(self, x):
        ....MY MODEL CODE....


class ResNet(nn.Module): 
    ....MY MODEL CODE....

    def forward(self, x):
      ....MY MODEL CODE....


class BaseResNet(nn.Module):
    ....MY MODEL CODE....

    def forward(self, x):
    ....MY MODEL CODE....

# Use BaseResNet as the model
model = BaseResNet(n_class=6)

loaded_model = torch.load("checkpoint.pth",map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

model.eval()
state_dict = loaded_model
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

###### Here's the error

`RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BaseResNet: Missing key(s) in state_dict: "resnet.conv1.weight", "resnet.bn1.weight", "resnet.bn1.bias", "resnet.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer1.0.conv1.weight", "resnet.layer1.0.bn1.weight", "resnet.layer1.0.bn1.bias", "resnet.layer1.0.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.layer1.0.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer1.0.conv2.weight", "resnet.layer1.0.bn2.weight", "resnet.layer1.0.bn2.bias", "resnet.layer1.0.bn2.running_mean", "resnet.layer1.0.bn2.running_var", "resnet.layer1.1.conv1.weight", "resnet.layer1.1.bn1.weight", "resnet.layer1.1.bn1.bias", "resnet.layer1.1.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.layer1.1.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer1.1.conv2.weight", "resnet.layer1.1.bn2.weight", "resnet.layer1.1.bn2.bias", "resnet.layer1.1.bn2.running_mean", "resnet.layer1.1.bn2.running_var", "resnet.layer2.0.conv1.weight", "resnet.layer2.0.bn1.weight", "resnet.layer2.0.bn1.bias", "resnet.layer2.0.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.layer2.0.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer2.0.conv2.weight", "resnet.layer2.0.bn2.weight", "resnet.layer2.0.bn2.bias", "resnet.layer2.0.bn2.running_mean", "resnet.layer2.0.bn2.running_var", "resnet.layer2.0.shortcut.0.weight", "resnet.layer2.0.shortcut.1.weight", "resnet.layer2.0.shortcut.1.bias", "resnet.layer2.0.shortcut.1.running_mean", "resnet.layer2.0.shortcut.1.running_var", "resnet.layer2.1.conv1.weight", "resnet.layer2.1.bn1.weight", "resnet.layer2.1.bn1.bias", "resnet.layer2.1.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.layer2.1.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer2.1.conv2.weight", "resnet.layer2.1.bn2.weight", "resnet.layer2.1.bn2.bias", "resnet.layer2.1.bn2.running_mean", "resnet.layer2.1.bn2.running_var", "resnet.layer3.0.conv1.weight", "resnet.layer3.0.bn1.weight", "resnet.layer3.0.bn1.bias", "resnet.layer3.0.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.layer3.0.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer3.0.conv2.weight", "resnet.layer3.0.bn2.weight", "resnet.layer3.0.bn2.bias", "resnet.layer3.0.bn2.running_mean", "resnet.layer3.0.bn2.running_var", "resnet.layer3.0.shortcut.0.weight", "resnet.layer3.0.shortcut.1.weight", "resnet.layer3.0.shortcut.1.bias", "resnet.layer3.0.shortcut.1.running_mean", "resnet.layer3.0.shortcut.1.running_var", "resnet.layer3.1.conv1.weight", "resnet.layer3.1.bn1.weight", "resnet.layer3.1.bn1.bias", "resnet.layer3.1.bn1.running_mean", "resnet.layer3.1.bn1.running_var", "resnet.layer3.1.conv2.weight", "resnet.layer3.1.bn2.weight", "resnet.layer3.1.bn2.bias", "resnet.layer3.1.bn2.running_mean", "resnet.layer3.1.bn2.running_var", "resnet.fc.weight", "resnet.fc.bias". Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "epoch", "model_state_dict", "optimizer_state_dict", "train_loss", "train_acc", "val_loss", "val_acc". Traceback: File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\Future_Founders\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__) File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\SEMESTER 7 - STARTUP CAMPUS\UI.py", line 102, in <module> model.load_state_dict(state_dict) File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\Future_Founders\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 2152, in load_state_dict raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).